# negative effect of running PAE kernel?

Tags: linux, 32-bit, kernel, linux-distributions, pae

Fedora, and other distros install a PAE kernel if the hardware supports it.

Are there any negative effect on running a PAE kernel on a machine with less than 3-4Gb ram ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.10 benchmarks including 32-bit and 32-bit PAE kernels:

http://www.phoronix.com/vr.php?view=14477

"...we did not find using Ubuntu's 32-bit PAE kernel to have a dramatic performance impact whether it be positive or negative"

The conclusion is probably the same for Fedora.

Stability doesn't seem to be a real issue.